# How to fix 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'coalesce'?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In a PySpark application, I tried to transpose a dataframe by transforming it into pandas and then I want to write the result in csv file. This is how I am doing it:

```
df = df.toPandas().set_index("s").transpose()
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", True).option("delimiter", ",").csv('dataframe')
```

When execution this script I get the following error:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'coalesce'
```

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you converted the spark dataframe into a pandas dataframe. A pandas dataframe do not have a `coalesce` method. You can see the documentation for pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).

When you use `toPandas()` the dataframe is already collected and in memory,
try to use the pandas dataframe method `df.to_csv(path)` instead.

Comment: that was problem, I fixed it!